# How to remove duplicated items in a sorted vector

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I currently have a `vector<int> c` which contains `{1,2,2,4,5,5,6}`
and I want to remove the duplicated numbers so that `c` will have
`{1,4,6}`. A lot of solutions on the internet seem to just remove one of the duplicates, but I'm trying to remove all occurrences of the duplicated number.

Assume `c` is always sorted.

I currently have

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  vector<int> c{1,2,2,4,5,5,6};
  for (int i = 0; i < c.size()-1; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<c.size();j++){
      if(c[i] == c[j]){
         // delete i and j? 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use two for-loops so that I can compare the current element and the next element. This is where my doubt kicked in. I'm not sure if I'm approaching the problem correctly.

Could I get help on how to approach my problem?

Comment: *This is where my doubt kicked in.* -- This is not a question, just a statement.  Is there anything wrong with the code you have now?  Does it produce the right results?

Comment: If equivalent values are always adjacent you can use [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) in a loop.

Comment: Quick question: is `c` guaranteed to be sorted, like it is in your current code?

Comment: if `c` is sorted, there's no reason to look behind the current number and past any number that is not equal to it in the inner loop.

Comment: If you want another approach to the problem:  1) Get a tally of the count of the number of items.  2) Once you get that, then group the numbers with a count > 1 at the end of the vector, and do one erase call to get rid of them.  One of the answers given already does this.  Erasing every time you find an equal number, plus making a nested loop to do this is a naive approach (imagine if it were `1 000 000` numbers instead of 7).

Comment: Just an idea: in a sorted list, an element is unique if and only if it's not equal to the two immediately adjacent elements (unless it's the starting and ending numbers, which have only one adjacent element). Perhaps you could try implementing this approach?

Comment: Use existing functionality:  [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Answer (score 7):

Almost any time you find yourself deleting elements from the middle of a vector, it's probably best to sit back and think about whether this is the best way to do the job--chances are pretty good that it isn't.

There are a couple of obvious alternatives to that. One is to copy the items you're going to keep into a temporary vector, then when you're done, swap the temporary vector and the original vector. This works particularly well in a case like you've shown in the question, where you're keeping only a fairly small minority of the input data.

The other is to rearrange the data in your existing vector so all the data you *don't* want is at the end, and all the data you do want is at the beginning, then resize your vector to eliminate those you don't want.

When I doubt, I tend to go the first route. In theory it's probably a bit less efficient (poorer locality of reference) but I've rarely seen a significant slow-down in real use.

That being the case, my initial take would probably be something on this general order:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> remove_all_dupes(std::vector<int> const &input) {

    if (input.size() < 2) // zero or one element is automatically unique
        return input;

    std::vector<int> ret;

    // first item is unique if it's different from its successor
    if (input[0] != input[1])
        ret.push_back(input[0]);

    // in the middle, items are unique if they're different from both predecessor and successor
    for (std::size_t pos = 1; pos < input.size() - 2; pos++)
        if (input[pos] != input[pos-1] && input[pos] != input[pos+1])
            ret.push_back(input[pos]);

    // last item is unique if it's different from predecessor
    if (input[input.size()-1] != input[input.size()-2])
        ret.push_back(input[input.size() - 1]);

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
    std::vector<int> uniques = remove_all_dupes(c);

    std::copy(uniques.begin(), uniques.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Probably a little longer of code than we'd really prefer, but still simple, straightforward, and efficient.

If you are going to do the job in place, the usual way to do it efficiently (and this applies to filtering in general, not just this particular filter) is to start with a copying phase and follow that by a deletion phase. In the copying phase, you use two pointers: a source and a destination. You start them both at the first element, then advance through the input with the source. If it meets your criteria, you copy it to the destination position, and advance both. If it doesn't meet your criteria, advance only the source.

Then when you're done with that, you resize your vector down to the number of elements you're keeping.

```cpp
void remove_all_dupes2(std::vector<int> & input) {
    if (input.size() < 2)   { // 0 or 1 element is automatically unique
        return;
    }

    std::size_t dest = 0;

    if (input[0] != input[1])
        ++dest;

    for (std::size_t source = 1; source < input.size() - 2; source++) {
        if (input[source] != input[source-1] && input[source] != input[source+1]) {
            input[dest++] = input[source];
        }
    }
    if (input[input.size()-1] != input[input.size()-2]) {
        input[dest++] = input[input.size() - 1];
    }
    input.resize(dest);
}
```

At least in my view, the big thing to keep in mind here is the general pattern. You'll almost certainly run into a lot more situations where you want to filter some inputs to those that fit some criteria, and this basic pattern of tracking source and destination, and copying only those from the source to the destination that fit your criteria works well in a *lot* of situations, not just this one.

Comment: Normally it would be obviously better (for efficiency) to compact in-place, then resize. 
 But if you want to get the unused space at the end of your `std::vector` handed back to the allocator (instead of reserved for future growth of this vector), we run into the fact that the C++ new/delete API doesn't include a realloc.  So to actually shrink (or grow), it has to allocate a new one and copy.  So you might as well copy on the fly to overlap computation / branch misses with cache misses.  (But if you don't know what size to reserve, you might have some reallocs to grow the dst...)

Comment: And BTW, lack of realloc seems like a bad decision that forces implementations to suck in some cases when they don't have to.  A simple implementation can just alloc+copy if there's no better way, but on some systems it's possible to grow by mapping more memory at the end of an allocation.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes--lack of a clean reallocation interface has bothered me for years, especially since for decades now we've had access to OS-level routines to allocate address space and physical pages separately, and map physical pages to addresses as needed. Hmmm...maybe if I were feeling ambitious I'd work on a proposal for that. Unfortunately, right now I'm feeling a lot more sleepy than ambitious...

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Just wondering, shouldn't the end of the for-loop in the second example be `input.size()-1`? I think otherwise you loose one element in a vector of all unique elements, don't you?

Answer (score 4):

This code is based on the insight that an element is unique in a sorted list if and only if it is different from both elements immediately adjacent to it (except for the starting and ending elements, which are adjacent to one element each). This is true because all identical elements *must* be adjacent in a sorted array.

```
void keep_unique(vector <int> &v){
    if(v.size() < 2){return;}

    vector <int> unique;

    // check the first element individually
    if(v[0] != v[1]){
        unique.push_back(v[0]);
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < v.size()-1; ++i){
        if(v[i] != v[i-1] && v[i] != v[i+1]){
            unique.push_back(v[i]);
        }
    }

    // check the last item individually
    if(v[v.size()-1] != v[v.size()-2]){
        unique.push_back(v[v.size()-1]);
    }

    v = unique;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally one has to be very careful when deleting from containers while iterating over them. C++ STL can do this easily and faster (on average) than using nested loops.

```cpp
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c{1,2,2,4,5,5,6};
    std::unordered_multiset<int> unique( c.begin(), c.end() );
    c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(),c.end(),[&](const auto& e){return unique.count(e)>1;}),c.end());

    for(auto e: c){
        std::cout<<e<<' ';
    }
}

//Output: 1 4 6
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::map<int,std::size_t>` and count the occurences this way.

Comment: Maybe `std:::unordered_multiset` instead of `std::multiset`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes that is a good idea, thank you.

Comment: The vector is guaranteed to be sorted, you can use much cheaper algorithms if you care about performance.  (One pass over the data).  [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) almost does what we want, but keeps 1 copy of duplicate elements instead of 0.  Modifying an example implementation of it (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) would be about as easy to understand.  This is weird, basically doing all the work for a CountingSort with a hash table of counts, but you use it modify the original instead of just getting the keys with val==1 in order.

Comment: TL:DR: don't build the algorithm around deleting elements from the original vector in the first place.  I guess this is a way to stick closer to the original question's guess at what might be a good approach (correctly avoiding removing one at a time) but other than that has little to recommend it.  If there's a way to reference adjacent elements from within a remove_if lambda, that could make it possible to use efficiently.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for you ideas, there was no mention of vector being sorted when I wrote the answer. That changes a lot of course. What do you mean to not delete them from original? That is exactly what OP wanted. How exactly does making a copy helps removing them?

Comment: I mean instead of using `delete` or `remove_if`, just write a whole new sequence of numbers, either into a new `std::vector` or in-place over the old contents.  The main point I was making is that once you have all the information you need in a convenient form (like keys of an ordered dictionary like std::map), it's probably best to just use that,  not also read the original vector again.  So you end up with the original compacted by copying into another form and rewriting.  But if you did need to preserve an original non-sorted order, yes your way makes sense.  I didn't know the Q changed.

Comment: Okay, I got it, thanks, I agree that it is better, but OP wanted to delete, not a new vector or at least they phrased it that way. There are plenty on answer, so I will like this one like this, OP can pick what they like.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to `std::unique`/`std::copy_if`, you might do:

```
void keep_unique(std::vector<int>& v){
    auto it = v.begin();
    auto w = v.begin();
    while (it != v.end())
    {
        auto next = std::find_if(it, v.end(), [&](int e){ return e != *it; });
        if (std::distance(it, next) == 1) {
            if (w != it) {
                *w = std::move(*it);
            }
            ++w;
        }
        it = next;
    }
    v.erase(w, v.end());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859a405fe7858f4f)

Comment: @xskxzr: OP wants, from `{1,2,2,4,5,5,6}` have `{1,4,6}` , not `{1,2,4,5,6}` (result from `std::unique`). `std::unique` doesn't fit OP's needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to move items occurring multiple times to the rear, then erase them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{

    std::vector<int> V {1,2,2,4,5,5,6};

    auto it = std::remove_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [&](const auto& val) 
    { 
        return std::count(V.begin(), V.end(), val) > 1;
    });

    V.erase(it, V.end());

    for (const auto& val : V)
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
4
6
```

For demo: https://godbolt.org/z/j6fxe1

Comment: This gives neat, simple code--but it's quite inefficient. It's an O(N^2) solution to an O(N) problem.

Comment: @JerryCoffin for small input, shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating in reverse <s>ensures an `O(N)` operation and does not cause element shifting when erasing because we are only ever erasing the last element in the vector</s>. Also, no other data structures need to be allocated.

For every element encountered, we check if the adjacent element is equal, and if so, remove all instances of that element.

Requires the vector to be sorted, or at least grouped by duplicates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> c {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6};
    
    for (int i = c.size() - 1; i > 0;) 
    {
        const int n = c[i];
        if (c[i - 1] == n)
        {
            while (c[i] == n)
            {
                c.erase(c.begin() + i--);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }

    }

    //output result
    for (auto it : c)
    {
        std::cout<<it;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
Output: 146
```

---

### Update

An actual O(N) implementation using a sentinel value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> c { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
    const int sentinel = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest(); //assumed that no valid member uses this value.
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size() - 1;) 
    {
        const int n = c[i];
        if (c[i + 1] == n)
        {
            while (c[i] == n)
            {
                c[i++] = sentinel;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    c.erase(std::remove(c.begin(),c.end(),sentinel), c.end());

    for (auto it : c) std::cout<< it << ' ';
}
```

Comment: I see two problems here, one in the description, and one in the code. The description says: "Iterating in reverse ensures an O(N) operation and does not cause element shifting when erasing because we are only ever erasing the last element in the vector." That's not really true. In the example, when you erase the `2`s, you're shifting the `4` and `6` over. And that gets us to the implementation: when you find duplicates, you erase them one at a time instead of as a group, so all the elements after them that you're keeping get shifted once for each element you erase.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh duh. Forgive me, I'm quitting coffee.

Comment: @Rotem: No need to ask forgiveness from me--if you're going to delete as you go (so to speak) iterating from end to beginning is a good idea. Just needed a bit more work to implement (and document) that idea as well as possible. But if I were in a position to grant forgiveness, I certainly would--quitting caffeine is *hard*!

Comment: The consecutive shifting is done either in forward or backward way, doing the complexity to O(N) due to `erase`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin One rather simple solution would be to flag all the values we want to erase with a sentinel value, then remove them all using remove_if after iteration but unfortunately I've run out of free time today

Comment: @Rotem: Why is the presented algorithm O(n)? It's looping over all entries of `c` in the outer loop and then calling the O(n) operation `erase` potentially for all of these O(n) iterations. So the algorithm complexity should be O(n²).

Comment: @Dreamer revised. Also added a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the proper use of iterators to avoid runtime errors.

Have a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    
    std::vector<int> c{1,2,2,4,5,5,6};

    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ){
        
        auto it2 = it;
        advance(it2, 1);
        
        bool isDuplicate = false;
        
        for(; it2 != c.end(); ++it2){
            if(*it == *it2){
                c.erase(it2);
                isDuplicate = true;
            }
        }
        
        if(isDuplicate){
            auto it3 = it;
            advance(it3, 1);
            c.erase(it);
            it = it3;
        }else{
            it++;
        }
    }
    
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); it++){
        
        std::cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 4 6
```

Comment: This will work, but the issue is that if the data were much larger than 7 items, the repeated calls to `erase()` will be an issue.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge. Can you share some reference about this so that I can update myself.

Comment: Look at the other answer that uses a data structure to get the count of the items before the erasure.  If there is enough space, the other approach would be more efficient for very large data sets.